# Code Returns from If(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission) segment

Tags: android, android-permissions

Hello Everyone I am creating Navigation Application using Android Studio and getting this error while doing.
My Code Stops in `if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission)` segment. Here i have toast statement. I have already provided `COARSE_LOCATION`, `FINE_LOCATION` and `INTERNET` permission in AndroidManifest file.
Following code given.

```
    public class Second extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
//Declaring Class Objects
Location location;
LocationManager lm;
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
//Data type for storing value of Longitude and Latitude
private double fromLongitude;
private double fromLatitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
    getLocation();
}

private void getLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

        Toast.makeText(this,"Issue with permission",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
    fromLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    fromLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(fromLatitude)+" "+String.valueOf(fromLongitude),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

//Starting Google API Client

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    googleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

//Stopping Google API Client
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
}
```

This prints `"Issue with Permission"`, that i have toast in if segment.

Comment: Since Marshmallow users have to explicitly grant these permissions, just having them in your Manifest is not enough. http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: got it brother thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try
this

**checkSelfPermission(Permission)** to check is permission is granted already or not.
    **requestPermissions(String[] permissions, int requestCode)** to request for permissions.
    **onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults)** to check for results whether permission is granted or not.

Request Permission like this

```
 private void askForPermission() {
   int hasWriteContactsPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
   if (hasWriteContactsPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       if(!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
           showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to Contacts",
                   new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                           requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                       }
                   });
           return;
       }
       requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
               REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
       return;
   }
```

}

Refer here to understand in detail https://coderzpassion.com/android-new-runtime-permissions/